# Openconnect won't disconnect in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, openconnect

I've installed openconnect and after establishing a session by the command

```
openconnect server_address
```

I just can't disconnect. In the manual, it's said a SIGINT signal would safely terminate the session, but that's not the case with me. Actually, I can't disconnect it even with a SIGKILL signal. Anyone knows what should I do? Is there a way to manually disconnect it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List all of the connections using `nmcli con`. The active connections will be styled in different color. In active connections, along your original connection name, you should see another connection named tun0 (or maybe something else). Type `nmcli con down tun0` or if it's something else, replace tun0 with that name. It will disconnect you.

Comment: `nmcli con down tun0` was killing DNS for me and I needed to reboot. What worked for me in 18.04 was installing `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` as [recommended here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033315/connecting-to-cisco-vpn-from-ubuntu-18-04-without-a-group-password?rq=1). Now openconnect works identically to vpnc.

Answer (score 6):

If you called `openconnect` in the foreground then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> interrupts the process and closes the connection. In case you started VPN in the background under the `userx` then you can call `kill` of `pkill` from the same `userx` or from the `root` (use `sudo`).
If you could not kill the process then either you had insufficient rights to do it or just misprinted the name. To check whether the process still exists use `$ ps -A | grep openconnect`.