# Connecting to Cisco VPN from Ubuntu 18.04 without a Group Password

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco

I've installed the cisco vpn client by running:

`sudo apt install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome`

When I try to connect to it however, it's asking me for a Group Password. My connection credentials don't include a group password, and I don't need one to connect to the same vpn using windows 10. There is an option to select "The password is not required" for the Group Password, but when I try to connect its still prompting me for a Group Password.

Is there a way to connect to the Cisco VPN without entering a Group Password?

Comment: I found this on a forum from 2009 stating that VPNC only replaces the legacy Cisco VPN client, not AnyConnect, which is SSL based. But since it's 9 years old I don't know how valid it is : https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-807778-start-0.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

vpnc replaces the legacy Cisco VPN client, which used IPSec and thus required a password for a group.

**Do you need to use Cisco AnyConnect?**

If you need to use the newer Cisco Anyconnect client, you can install [openconnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome` This will add an Anyconnect compatible option to the VPN GUI under your network settings.

You can also initiate a connection by entering `sudo openconnect YOURVPN.COM` in the terminal. This will then prompt you for credentials and group settings, much like the Cisco AnyConnect client does.

If the GUI method seems confusing or isn't working at first, try the terminal method to get details about the connection you are making. I needed to restart my computer before the GUI worked. You can close the terminal connection by pressing ctrl+c in the terminal window.

After restarting, if you do not have any other credentials except a username, password, and group, you can use the GUI by:

1. Select the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Protocol
2. Enter your VPN address into the Gateway text box
3. Save the VPN Settings
4. Activate the VPN
5. Follow the prompt for your user credentials

Comment: Thanks. This helped me connect through without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can use these commands to connect to Cisco VPN in terminal:

```
sudo /sbin/modprobe tun
sudo apt install openconnect 
sudo openconnect yourvpnserver.com:port
```

then it asks for `username` and `password` and you are done.

Comment: Is not disconnecting using the terminal!! Why?