# Unable to open "Cisco Anyconnect Secure mobility client" on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after the complete installation

Tags: vpn, openvpn, cisco

I am having problems on a Cisco VPN.

**ISSUE:** Unable to open "Cisco Anyconnect Secure mobility client" on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after the complete installation.

I am able to see the icon on the application menu; but, when I launch the app it doesn't open. Below is the screenshot \ logs for your reference:

[image: Screenshot of terminal logs]

Comment: You have some options in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033315/connecting-to-cisco-vpn-from-ubuntu-18-04-without-a-group-password

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the exactly same problem, the VPN was working but couldn't see the GUI, I found that is because of some missing dependency (`libpangox-1.0-0` and `libcanberra-gtk-module`), try installing it:

```
sudo apt install libpangox-1.0-0 libcanberra-gtk-module
```

You may check if you need anything more or have other errors by running the UI executable, mine was installed on

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect
```

You can run `bin/vpnui` and check what error you may have, hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Kennedy, Thanks for helping me out. I am able to see the GUI after installed the dependency. Really appreciate your support. Long live linux :-)

Comment: This worked for me thanks! Ubuntu 18.04 too (fresh install)

Comment: It works also for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I also installed `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` which fixed the issue

Comment: Thanks for helping this community