# [Ubuntu 18.04]Cannot connect to Cisco VPN

Tags: 18.04, vpn, cisco

I am trying to connect to some CISCO VPN from Ubuntu 18.04 (which I connect ok from Windows). This is not anyConnect.

I installed using:

apt install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome

Now I am able to configure the VPN connection(gateway, user/pass, group/pass), even import the profile (.pcf) directly but I am not able to connect to any of them. I try to turn them on and it turns off automatically. No log, no error message, nothing at all.

Can you please give some idea how to troubleshoot/resolve.

Answer (score 1):

I am also searching on this, so far I found this works for me (I can login and pass the 2FA with okta verify): https://askubuntu.com/a/1038863