# Cannot start vpnagentd service on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco

Anyone can help how can I solve these errors that I recieve while trying to start vpnagentd? Seems like there are some c++ libraries are missed in my system, but I can't found them

```
➜ service vpnagentd status
● vpnagentd.service - LSB: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client for Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/vpnagentd; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-03-08 12:56:28 +03; 8s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5706 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/vpnagentd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5725 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/vpnagentd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 73 Invoked Function: dlopen Return Code: 2 (0x00000002) Description: unknown
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 145 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 182 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::createSingletonInstance Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: CHostConfigMgr File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 126 Invoked Function: CNetInterface Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: CreateSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/HostConfigMgr.cpp Line: 196 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: CMainThread File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 1357 Invoked Function: CHostConfigMgr::createSingletonInstance Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: CreateSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 591 Invoked Function: CMainThread Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Error Message to display to the user: The VPN client agent was unable to create the client host configuration manager.
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Function: process File: ../../vpn/Agent/vpnagentd.cpp Line: 256 Invoked Function: CMainThread::CreateSingletonInstance Return Code: -22216695 (0xFEAD0009) Description: NWMGRHELPER_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
сак 08 12:56:28 pavel-desktop acvpnagent[5734]: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Agent stopped, version 4.4.04030
```

Comment: found solution to use anyconnect vpn via terminal
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033315/connecting-to-cisco-vpn-from-ubuntu-18-04-without-a-group-password